# Remote debugging on Windows 8.1 not pro tablet

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging

I've developed a Windows Store app, that works great on my Dev machine (Win 8.1 Pro; VS 2013 Community Update 4)

I try to connect over my network to my Windows 8.1 tablet (Not pro, Dell Venue 8"). I can see both devices on the network. My Dev box can see shares on the tablet, and the tablet can see shares on the Dev box.

When I try to run remote debugging, it asks for authentication. I am logged in on both machines  (which I believe are on the same homegroup/workgroup) with the same Username/password, but it still asks for authentication, and tries to use my Dev PC's name as the domain.

What am I missing? Since the tablet is not Pro, I do not have the local security policy editor.

Comment: Have you installed the [Remote Debugging Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402291) (ARM) package for VS 2013 on that machine?

Comment: No, since it is an Atom processor, and it is not running windows RT, I did not install the ARM package, only the standard remote debugging tools package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try setting the options on the Remote Debugger to "No Authentication"? Note, this could be a security problem so do so at your own risk.

[image: Remote Debugger configuration]

Comment: Not sure what changed, but I couldn't get to those screens. Now I can, and with No Authentication, I can debug. Thank you. I won't leave it like this, but it got me going! Thanks! I also couldn't find this info when Binging it.